# arduino sketch on Win7 vs. MAC op system?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a friend who is just getting started with Arduino UNO.  He downloaded a sketch and is using a UNO on Mac OS.  He loaded the sketch and verified.  it comes up with errors.  He sent me the same sketch and i opened it under Win7 arduino software.  verified, and it says it is fine.  i made an arduino file and emailed it back to him.  he is still getting the same errors.  can anyone help and let me know what is wrong?  i am not a MAC expert and wonder why  this works in win and not MAC????????  appreicate any help anyone can give me

Comment: Can you post the source code and the errors please? It's difficult to suggest anything useful otherwise.

Comment: Do you both have the Uno selected as target device in the IDE?

Comment: Are you using the same version of the Arduino IDE.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same issue with Mac OSX 10.6.8 vs Windows XP SP3 using the same IDE version. I don't have a definitive answer for you, but I know that Microsoft has more frequent updates compared to Apple, which could be the reason. I suspect my issue and your friend's issue is the GCC compiler we're using. The compiler would be updated on OSX only when you update your entire OSX version. To get around that, there are third-party package managers: Homebrew and MacPorts that would allow you to just update the GCC compiler for example.